# window form TextBox no assign any value from datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, methods, invoke

// method

```
    private void txtBoxDateView(string column_name, string txt_box_value)
    {
        if (ColumnName != null && txtBoxValue != null)
        {
            ColumnName = null;
            txtBoxValue = null;
        }
        ColumnName = column_name;
        txtBoxValue = txt_box_value;
        DV = new DataView(dt);

        DV.RowFilter = string.Format(column_name + " like '%{0}%'", txt_box_value);
        dgvInventory1.DataSource = DV;
    }
```

/invoke method

```
        private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBoxDateView("ItemName", txtBrand.Text);

    }


    //select data when double click

        private void dgvInventory1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        txtId.Text = dgvInventory1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtCatg.Text = dgvInventory1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtName.Text = dgvInventory1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        //below this code doesnt assign value
        txtBrand.Text = dgvInventory1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString(); 
        txtLocation.Text = dgvInventory1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        txtQty.Text = dgvInventory1.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString(); // 
      txtqty this have another function to do

    }
```

when I double-click the row, the value will only assigns to txtId,txtName, and txtCatg. I have been checked my SSMS. The cell is correct. and when I debug, the textbox will assign "" empty value even there have data. after I test a few time ago.  txtBoxValue = txt_box_value; will become  empty when each time run. it will only show the txtId.text value.  and all is varchar except (txtqty). Any wrong with my method?

Comment: You are using `txtBoxDateView' method or direct invoke?

Comment: @BaskarJohn i m using txtboxDataView method

Comment: `txtBoxDateView("ItemName", txtBrand.Text);` i think you are filtering record with wrong text field. `txtName_TextChanged` accessing `txtBrand.text` value

Comment: @BaskarJohn yes u are right thk bro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that, the text change event will affect `CurrentRow`

When the `TextChange` event triggered, its changing the datasource with filtered records.

to over come that. use the below statement in mouse double click event

```
        var dataRow = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
        if (dataRow != null)
        {
            var row = dataRow.Row;
            txtId.Text = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            txtCatg.Text = row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
            txtName.Text = row.ItemArray[2].ToString();
            //below this code doesnt assign value
            txtBrand.Text = row.ItemArray[3].ToString();
            txtLocation.Text = row.ItemArray[4].ToString();
            txtQty.Text = row.ItemArray[5].ToString();
            //txtqty this have another function to do
        }
```

the above line not depend the view. And using the direct table row data. 
Also the `txtqty` function also you can use the `DataRow`